# Need to print one month before date

Tags: sql

Wanted to print the one month before the actual Date

If I mentioned FromPeriod=01.10.2023 then it should print the FromPeriod date=01.09.2023
and this FromPeriod column was already mentioned on other table and I leftjoin that table

```
DECLARE @yourDate DATE = '01-OCT-2021'
    ----select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @yourDate)-1, -1)
    --SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @yourDate), -1)

    SELECT EOMONTH(@yourDate, -1)
```

I tried this and from above query i got the last date of september month

but i wanted to print 01-Sept-2021

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: I also didn't see what this had to do with ASP.Net, so I removed that tag as well.

Comment: *"I tried this and from above query i got the last date of september month" of course you will, `EOMONTH` means **E**nd **o**f **Month**; the last date in September is the *end of the month*. Why not just subtract a month from your date value? I am sure the DBMS you are using as a `DATEADD` (like) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@yourDate,-2))
```

This returns you the date in your default format. If you need it to be in the same format as you entered:

```
SELECT UPPER(FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@yourDate,-2)),'dd-MMM-yyyy'))
```

but this will now be a string and not a date.